# R markdown does not covert .tex table to word document, while it works fine in pdf. How to make both result consistent?

Tags: r, pdf, ms-word, r-markdown, pandoc

I want to put a `iv.tex` into a `test.rmd` and export it as a `word_document`.

**The problem is it does not show the table in the `.docx` but it does in `.pdf`.**

**My question: How to have the same result in both `.docx` and `.pdf`?** Please see below for additional information. Thank you.

The following `word_test.rmd` compiles to `.docx`, but it does not show the table. I tried: 1. `\input`, 2. `=latex`. None of them works. See the output image and code below

### `word_test.rmd`

[image: word_text.docx output image here]

````latex
---
title: "word_test"
output: "word_document"
date: '2022-08-09'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Test Tables with `input`

\input{"iv.tex"}


## Test Tables with `=latex`

```{=latex}
\include{"iv.tex"}
```
````

While the same code does produce the desired outcome if its output is `pdf_document`, see image and code below.

### `pdf_test.rmd`

[image: pdf_test.rmd output image here]

````latex
---
title: "pdf_test"
output: "pdf_document"
date: '2022-08-09'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Test Tables with `input`

\input{"iv.tex"}


## Test Tables with `=latex`

```{=latex}
\input{"iv.tex"}
```
````

### `iv.tex`

`iv.tex` is a table, see below.

```latex
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering\scriptsize    
  \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
  \caption{myTable\label{tab:mlogit}}
  \begin{tabular}{l*{9}{c}}
  \hline\hline
                      &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}\\
                    %  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{lexpenditure}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Poverty}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Dummy for multidimensional poverty index (k=0.33)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{lexpenditure}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Poverty}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Dummy for multidimensional poverty index (k=0.33)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{lexpenditure}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Poverty}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Dummy for multidimensional poverty index (k=0.33)}\\
  \hline
  var1    &      0.000\sym{***}&    5e-15\sym{***}&    -0.00551         &      -0.000\sym{***}&   5e-15\sym{***}&       0.000\sym{***}&      -0.000\sym{***}&    5e-15\sym{***}&       0.000\sym{***}\\
                      &   (0.000)         &  (5e-15)         &   (0.000)         &    (0.000)         &  (5e-15)         &    (0.000)         &    (0.000)         &  (5e-15)         &    (0.000)         \\
  var2  &      0.000\sym{***}&   5e-15\sym{**} &      -0.000\sym{***}&       0.000\sym{***}&    5e-15\sym{***}&      -0.000\sym{***}&       0.000\sym{***}&   5e-15         &      -0.000\sym{***}\\
                      &   (0.000)         &  (5e-15)         &    (0.000)         &    (0.000)         &  (5e-15)         &     (0.000)         &    (0.000)         &  (5e-15)         &     (0.000)         \\
  var3     &      0.000\sym{***}&    5e-15\sym{***}&     -0.000\sym{***}&      -0.122         &    5e-15         &       0.174         &      -0.135         &   5e-15\sym{***}&       0.235         \\
                      &    (0.000)         &  (5e-15)         &    (0.000)         &     (0.000)         &  (5e-15)         &     (0.000)         &     (0.000)         &  (5e-15)         &     (0.000)         \\
  var4          &      0.000\sym{***}&   5e-15\sym{**} &     -0.000\sym{***}&       0.000\sym{***}&   5e-15\sym{***}&      -0.000\sym{***}&       0.000\sym{***}&    5e-15\sym{***}&      -0.000\sym{***}\\
                      &    (0.000)         &  (5e-15)         &    (0.000)         &    (0.000)         &  (5e-15)         &    (0.000)         &    (0.000)         &  (5e-15)         &    (0.000)         \\
  \hline
  Observations        &       999         &       999         &       999         &       999         &       999         &       999         &       999         &       999         &       999         \\
  \hline\hline
  \multicolumn{10}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
  \multicolumn{10}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
```

Comment: It's not possible to render the latex code in a word document, during file conversion pandoc will ignore that latex part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind raw snippets is that it allows to include some extra content, that does not apply to other formats. So normally, R Markdown won't touch these snippets but pass them through, but only when the output format matches. That's why the table shows up in PDF, but not Docx.

R Markdown is very flexible, so we can modify its behavior. The best approach here is to use a [Lua filter](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/lua-filters.html) to parse the LaTeX code when going to a format that does not support LaTeX snippets.

Save the following code to a file `parse-latex.lua`, and put it in the same directory as your `.Rmd` file.

```lua
if FORMAT == 'latex' then
  return {}
end

function RawBlock (raw)
  if raw.format:match 'tex' then
    print(raw.text)
    return pandoc.read(raw.text, 'latex').blocks
  end
end
```

Then instruct R Markdown to invoke the filter by changing your YAML header to

```yaml
---
title: "word_test"
output:
  word_document:
    pandoc_args:
      - '--lua-filter=parse-latex.lua'
date: '2022-08-09'
---
```

There is one remaining problem though: pandoc is not good at knowing when the parser should be in math mode, so the `\ifmmode` in your `\sym` definition doesn't work the way it does in LaTeX. Replace it with this instead:

```latex
\def\sym#1{\textsuperscript{#1}}
```

Your tables should now show up even in docx output.

---

I've put the filter into a repo at [tarleb/parse-latex](https://github.com/tarleb/parse-latex); see there for more details and Quarto usage instructions.

Comment: Woah, nice! I am now fully convinced to learn Lua. Thanks.

Comment: the table in .docx does not render as intended. For example, the asterisk (`*`) has been rendered as the following: `^*^* p<0.05, ^**^(**) p<0.01, ^***^(***) p<0.001`, see updated in the question for detail. Thank you